# White block instead of text using SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

Today I notice a very strange thing, instead of the label that I want to display 0 I get a white block, even though fontColor is set to black

```
// In MPSingleton
let gameFontRegular = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 1.5)

func addText(withText: String, textcolor: UIColor) -> SKLabelNode {

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: MPSingleton.shared.gameFontRegular?.fontName);
    label.text = withText;
    label.fontColor = textcolor
    label.fontSize = self.btnSize/4

    label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center;
    label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center;
    label.zPosition = 122;

    return label

}
```

But this doesn't happen that often, and I don't know why?

// update 1

```
var scoreInt: SKLabelNode!

scoreInt = addText("\(score)", textcolor: MPSingleton.shared.bgColor)
self.gameOverNode.addChild(scoreInt)
```

// update 2
Instead of Best Score : 30, there is a white blank space, the color of the text is #666666 and with fontSize = 20.7142857142857

[image]

Comment: where did you call addChild for your label?

Comment: I add the node to which I assign the returned node

Comment: please show the code where you call addChild.

Comment: I updated the question :)

Comment: If I launch the game 100 times this will happen one or two times. And only break with numbers below 10

Comment: Is there any chance that `MPSingleton` isn't initialised properly before calling your methods?

Comment: @grape1 Can you upload an image which shows an issue ? Try to println everything (label.text, label.fontSize, label.FontColor as well as MPSingleton.shared.gameFontRegular?.fontName) and see when that happens what are differences.

Comment: font name = HelveticaNeue, text = Best Score : 30,  color = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.4 0.4 0.4 1. The labels that don't break have the same data, expect the text

Comment: And also I added a screenshot